# Bluemix_Adapter_SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, keystore, mobilefirst-adapters, ibm-mobile-services

> Mobile app(andriod) -> **Middleware (Bluemix)** -> Backend Server (.net)

As per the Bluemix(Adapter) logs I can see, Mobile App can access Adapter APIs but getting `java.security.cert.CertificationException` when accessing Backend Serve's APIs (https) from Adapter(Bluemix)

UnTrusted SSL certificate has been added in Backend Server. So, is there any configuration required to be done in Bluemix to access secured Backend APIs? OR should I have to add keystore files in Bluemix?

Please see below image for error/exception.
[image]

Comment: Is that a JS adapter or Java adapter?

Comment: This is Java Adapter

Answer (score 1):

This document describes what needs to be done to connect to a backend over SSL , from a Java script adapter:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/17/SSL-connection-from-adapters/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through this link and followed the same steps but still getting same error. But one thing is i have not restarted the Mobilefirst server because whenever I restarted the Server/ app then all the changes I have made or file files addition got completely vanished. Bluemix initialized everything on app restart.

Comment: You are on a developer plan?

Comment: No. Client has purchased the license.